# outdated python-tool? obvious mistake?

Tags: python

Im tryin to use the following tool:https://code.google.com/p/pymsi2lmp/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcompass-fit

one of its modules raises an error...heres the source:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
sys.path.append(sys.path[0] +'/../pymsi2lmp')
import pymsi2lmp
from modify_frc import term_parameter_count as count

# Calls pymsi2lmp and returns the which parameters are missing and
# the total number of unknown coefficients.
def call_msi2lmp(model, frc):
    missing = pymsi2lmp.msi2lmp(model, frc)
    #print "missing:"
    #print missing
    unknown = {}
    for m in missing:
        if not m[0] in unknown: unknown[m[0]] = []
        unknown[m[0]].append(m[1])

    ct = sum([sum([count(m,a) for a in unknown[m]]) for m in unknown])
    return unknown,ct
```

Im getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Im not very familiar with python and the sum-command at the bottom is too complicated for me with that implicit loops etc.

Do you see an obvious mistake here, or is this something more complex, depending on the other modules?

Any hints?

thx in advance

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post the full traceback instead of the last line. Even if it looks like spam to you, it contains information helpful to solve this.